# Enabling S3 EventBridge Notifications via Client

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-event-bridge

Does anyone know how to enable the EventBridge notifications via the s3 API?   The documentation is not very helpful: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-notification-configuration.html.

[EventBridgeConfiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo5oj.png)

Comment: Have you tried the example in the documentation you shown? That works. Can you share error massage if you're seeing some?

Answer (score 0):

All events get sent to the default bus in the account, so there is nothing to configure. This makes the documentation and the call structure confusing. It makes more sense if you translate the API Call into XML.

```js
await s3Client.putBucketNotificationConfiguration({
  Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
  NotificationConfiguration: {
    EventBridgeConfiguration: {},
  }
}).promise();
```